# Services not starting on boot (but will start manually) on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

After rebooting my machine, I have found many services have stopped starting automatically. If I start them with their init scripts once the machine is booted, they start without any problems. Strangely enough, if I run `sudo init 5` once logged in, most services will start (although some still seem to refuse without manually running their init scripts.

I can't think of anything that's changed since I last rebooted my machine and system logs don't seem to show anything useful. Any help is always appreciated!

**Update**: I have verified both by using `chkconfig` and examining scripts in `/etc/rc*.d` folders that the services are configured to start and that the scripts run correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug of 9.10.  See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/497299

I changed the line 9 of /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf from "start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)"
to "start on filesystem and net-device-up". It's worked for me.

Comment: I'll check the system when I get into the office today, but this sounds exactly like what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Thanks! I tried updating `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` as you suggested,which didn't help. However, updating `/etc/network/interfaces` as suggested in the bug report did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the services are activated for your default runlevel?
You can get your current runlevel with `runlevel`. You can verify the activated runlevels with `chkconfig --list <servicename>`.

Comment: `chkconfig` isn't installed by default in Ubuntu; you need to install the `chkconfig` package.

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be posted as a comment. But yes, I have verified that the services are activated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you add those services? Usually with Ubuntu you add and/remove links to the rc services with the update-rc.d command:

```
root@hostname:~# /usr/sbin/update-rc.d
usage: update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> defaults [NN | SS KK]
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> start|stop NN runlvl [runlvl] [...] .
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
                -n: not really
                -f: force
```

I'd try to update the init scripts in question with that command to see if that addresses.

Now if the services were not added via apt-get and your installed them manually, that's a different story. Which services in question did not start?

Comment: All the services were installed automatically with apt-get and were previously working. Services that didn't start include ssh, webmin, monit, and several others. I don't have a complete list.

(As an aside, I installed monit AFTER I had this problem and it also does not start)

Comment: I could be wrong, but it sounds like its at init 1, since most of the multi-user servers start at around 2 (for Ubuntu , at least):

root@host:~# who -r
         run-level 2  2009-12-29 05:47

I thought that it is set to level 1 by accident, but as it turns out, there is no inittab for some time.  :( that said, you may want to check anyway and if you see that it has been installed, change it to either level 2 or 3.